# What does 'nanm' mean?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, transforms

For a camera object, under Transform/Location, the x,y,z values are all nanm.  What does that mean?

[image]

Comment: NaN is Not a Number and I am guessing Blender was set to meters. Beyond that I have no idea why you are seeing it. What version of Blender and can you upload a copy showing the issue? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: How did you get into this situation? Is it possible to get this without assigning nan to the properties manually with Python?

Answer (score 1):

"Not a Number" appears when you excede a range. This means your object is too close/far away. Move it closer or away.

Comment: Too far would give inf or -inf, too close would be rounded to 0. Moving it will just change the nan value as far as I understand so it will be fixed in any case, but I don't think this explains, why this is there and what nan means in this context.